# Lists, matrices and dataframes in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am working in python and am having problems understanding the relations between lists, numpy arrays and matrices and pandas dataframes.

I know the following, to go from a df to a matrix is enough to call as_matrix().
I am now trying to create a numpy matrix from a double list. My list has 3 lists of 891 elements (but it could be any number).

Say the list is tmp, I have `len(tmp) = 3` and `len(tmp[0]) = 891`.
Then I did `tt = numpy.matrix(tmp)`.
If I now do:

```
print tt.shape
```

this is (1,3).
Now, I tried also

```
print tt[0].shape
```

and

```
print tt[0][0].shape
```

and

```
print tt[0][0][0].shape
```

and the result is always (1,3)
This makes no sense to me.
Shouldn't `tt` be a (3, 891) matrix like tmp?

If I do

```
print len(tmp)
print len(tmp[0])
print([len(row) for row in tmp])
```

I get

```
3
891
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: "My list has 3 lists of 891 elements" <- prove it. :-)  What does `print([len(row) for row in tmp])` return?

Comment: I added a part at the end. If i do what you asked I get an error, but I also wrote why I think I should have a (3 by 891) matrix

Comment: The error message makes it very clear your list does *not* contain 3 lists of 891 numbers, but it has a `None` in there.  You have a sequence of length 3, agreed; the 0th element has length 891, agreed; but it's clear that either the first or second element is actually None.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. There is something wrong in my code, I assumed the three lists were the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that a item of matrix is ..... a matrix. Since you have only one line, `tt==tt[0]` and so on. Indexing array is different, `ndim(a[0])` is more intuitively `ndim(a)-1`.

Comment: Yes, it was a mistake in my code. I should have checked all the columns.